# Fill a multidimensional javascript array matrix with default value

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Following code works fine but I was asked to find a bug in following code. Can anyone point out.

```
function defaultMatrix(size) { 
    var defaultValue = 0;
    var row = [];
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i=0; i < size; i++) { row.push(defaultValue); }
    for (var i=0; i < size; i++) { matrix.push(row); }
    return matrix;
}

console.log(defaultMatrix(6));
```

Comment: `row` is being reused. IOW, each row will be a reference to the exact same array, so a modification to one row will affect all rows.

Comment: Can you give any more information about how the function is expected to act?

Comment: It should fill matrix with default zeros. That is all I have got. So I think answer provided by @bgoldst makes sense. I have tested by changing one value and it causes to change in all rows.

Comment: The only error is that i is defined twice

Answer (score 1):

I think the error it's in JS the arrays are referenced objects. So, in your case you create a **matrix** only once. And you push it in the rows.

So in that case, if you do a code like:

```
let arr = defaultMatrix(2);
arr[0][0] = 1;
```

And you display arr[1][0] and arr[2][0] the value is "1" because the array on all arr[n] are the same.

For solve that you must create a new array in each row. For solve your code you only need change 1 line:

```
for (var i=0; i < size; i++) { matrix.push(row.slice()); }
```

The [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice) create a copy of the current array.

But you can do it all in one line, like this:

```
function defaultMatrix(size, defaultValue = 0) { 
    return Array(size).fill(0).map(() => {return Array(size).fill(defaultValue)});
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are adding size-times the same row which ends up being size*size big.

```
function defaultMatrix(size) { 
    var defaultValue = 0;
    var rows = [];
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i=0; i < size; i++) { 

        // create row
        rows[i] = []; 

        // create cells
        for (var j=0; j < size; j++) {
            rows[i].push(defaultValue);
        }

        // add row to matrix
        matrix.push(rows[i]);
    }
    return matrix;
}

console.log(defaultMatrix(6));
```

If you want to initialize the matrix with 0 every time, then you can further simplify the script like this:

```
function defaultMatrix(size) { 
    var matrix = [];
    for (var i=0; i < size; i++) { 
        matrix.push(new Array(size));
    }
    return matrix;
}

console.log(defaultMatrix(6));
```